# ASP.NET MVC Routing with IIS Default Application with Alias

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having a website, say www.mywebsite.com, to which I want to add my ASP.NET MVC application which could be accessible from the link **www.mywebsite.com/MyApplication**. The problem begins when the action method of a controller is called which redirects to **mywebsite.com/Home/MyAction** which gives a 404. The route mapping done currently is as follows:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Please advice me on what I should be follow regarding the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current route states that it should only match routes that start with `api`. Furthermore you're only mapping an HttpRoute (which is for ASP.NET MVC Web API)

Instead you should add a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                       // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}",                         // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction"}  // Parameter defaults
            );
```